# How to write the query for retrieving id from sqlite database table in iphone apps

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am new to using the SQLite database in iphone apps. I have created a database with login table in it and added the database to the project. Login table contains 3 fields `ID`, `Username` and `Password` fields. I am entering the username and password in the textfields of the view. Now I am looking of how to retrieve the id from the login table when username and password entered are correct by checking the table. Can anyone help out in this.

**My Code:**

```
-(void)checkInDatabase
{
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //uid = "select count(*) from logins where Username==txtusername.text and Password==txtpassword.text";
        NSString* sql =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select id from login where Username =%s and Password=%s;",txtusername.text,txtpassword.text];

        [sql UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW);
            {
                uid =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            uid =0;
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: sql = "select id from login where Username =txtusername.text and Password=txtpassword.text";

I am writing my select statement like this i dont think its working.

Comment: Have you verified you can access you sqlite db?  You should post some code.  Also, edit your post instead of commenting on it.

Comment: Hi Rob i have edited my question with new code, take a look at it.

Thanks

Comment: Nice.  Check out the second part of my answer.  You need to pass the UTF8 version of sql to sqlite3_prepare_v2().

Comment: Also, there's no need for the standalone '[sql UTF8String];' statement.

Comment: I have changed it too. Even then same problem continues.

Comment: i am getting the correct output if i give the default values for username an d password. But i am unable to figure out what to do for giving values that were entered in the text fields to the username and password.

Comment: const char *sql = "select id from login where Username='Akhil' and Password='Chowdary'"; Its working properly.  Code in which i am giving the default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by writing the code like this:

```
NSString* sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                  @"select id from login where Username='%@' and  
                                  Password='%@'",txtusername.text,txtpassword.text];
```

Its working good for me now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your SQL statement in a format usable by sqlite3.  You might do something like this:

```
NSString *select = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select id from login where Username=%s and Password=%s;", txtusername.text, txtpassword.text];
```

Since sqlite is a C library you will need to get the UTF8 version of the select string and pass that to the sqlite lib:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
```